# Matched date documents from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Tried to get matched date's document from mongodb using mongoose but not working.How to do that?
In my collection many documents are there.
Here my code is working blindly.If i give 2020-06-02 getting all documents.I want to get matched date documents only.Please help anyone.

Mongodb Data:

```
[{

{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1df67b272e2d4cf36f70"),
pname:"Test 1", 
category:"Choco 1",
tdate:2020-06-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5gdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f72"),
pname:"Test 2", 
category:"Choco 3",
tdate: 2020-06-02T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5kdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f74"),
pname:"Test 5", 
category:"Choco 6",
tdate: 2020-05-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5ewd1df67b272e2d4cf36f75"),
pname:"Test 6", 
category:"Choco 8",
tdate: 2020-06-02T18:30:00.000+00:00
} 
]
```

data.controller.js:

```
let getData = dbc.model(collectionname);
getData.find({
            tdate: {
                $gte: moment('2020-06-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('day').toDate();
            }
        }, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("Successful loaded");
                console.log(docs);
                res.json({ data: docs, msg: 'Data loaded.' });
            }
        });
```

I have given 2020-06-02 so my output docs should be like

console.log(docs);

```
[ 
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5gdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f72"),
pname:"Test 2", 
category:"Choco 3",
tdate: 2020-06-02T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5ewd1df67b272e2d4cf36f75"),
pname:"Test 6", 
category:"Choco 8",
tdate: 2020-06-02T18:30:00.000+00:00
} 
]
```

Comment: If possible you can save the date in ISO format in the database ("2020-06-01T00:00:00Z") then the query will work. For that, `tdate` type should be `date`. You can get the date in above format by `new Date()`

Comment: @Vishnu:Ok..I will check it

Comment: @Vishnu: Not able to save ISO format in mongodb

Comment: If those are strings in the documents, and the strings are always in that format, and always in the same timezone, you can use `{$gte:"2020-06-02", $lt:"2020-06-03"}` to match a day.

Comment: @Joe:Not String

Comment: So if the are not string and not ISODate, what are they?